# Ruby add an integer to a hex value or convert integer to hex

Tags: ruby, hex

I am trying to convert an integer to hex in ruby but i am having trouble. I need it to be in the format \x00 but it seems this is not possible if you do not set it manually?

```
count = 5

hex = "\x0#{count}"

puts hex.inspect # "\x005" but i need it to be "\x05"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

["\x00".unpack("C").first + count].pack("C")

somebody in #ruby @ irc.freenode.net answered it